# makeコマンドでエラー「make: Nothing to be done for `mysql'.」が解消できない

Tags: macos, makefile

## 解決したいこと

Dockerを使ってMySQLのコンテナを立てられるようにした。（これはできている）
MySQLにアクセスするコマンドを、`make mysql` のようにサブコマンドにしたかったが、やってみると下記エラーが発生してしまう。

```
make: Nothing to be done for `mysql'.
```

## ソースコード

Makefile

```
.PHONY: mysql 
mysql: 
  docker-compose exec mysql mysql -u root --password=passwd sample_db
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql@sha256:870892ea5cc8c623b389717c2eedd58248c82a8569d7601ede62a63d527641bd 
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: passwd
    volumes:
      - ./.tmp/docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./docker/db/my.cnf:/usr/local/etc/my.cnf
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

## やったこと

下記コマンドは成功する。

```
% docker-compose exec mysql mysql -u root --password=passwd sample_db
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 8.0.23 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

しかし、下記コマンドは失敗する

```
% make mysql                                                         
make: Nothing to be done for `mysql'.
```

問題が初歩的すぎるのか、自分があほなのか、
「make: Nothing to be done for ''」
これで検索すると、ヒットする情報はもっと難解な問題にぶち当たっているように見えるものしか見つけられず...

わかる方がいらっしゃれば、何卒、解決方法をご教示願います。

## 環境

M1 Mac

```
% make -v   
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

他に必要な情報があればコメントください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず気になるのは`Makefile`中のターゲット`mysql`のコマンド行が水平タブで始まっていないように見えることです。コマンド行の左はスペースではなく水平タブでなければなりません。ただ、その場合は違ったエラーメッセージになると思うので、これは的外れだと思いますが、一応確認してください。

`make`がターゲット（この場合`mysql`）の生成のために何を試しているかは

```
make -d mysql
```

で詳しく追ってみることができます。まずはそれをやってみてください。

Comment: コマンド行がタブでなくスペース開始、かつ、パスワード部分にコロン `:` が入っている、となると、コマンド行は別の依存関係（複数依存元、複数依存先）と解釈されて `mysql:` ターゲットの実行コマンドが空＝Nothing to be done になるのであろうと推測します。 see also; https://teratail.com/questions/onkyq7miyzked0